# I want to print prime numbers with this function. Where is my mistake?

Tags: c

Write a program to find the prime numbers between 1 and 100 and display them on the screen. In this program, the function prime () must take an integer from where it is called, return 1 if this number is prime, and return 0 if not.

I just take this output.

`2`

My codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int n);
int main() {
    int i,n,result1,result2,p;
    
    for(i=2;i<=100;i++){
        p=prime(i);
        if(p==1){
            printf("%d",i);
            
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
int prime(int n){
    int i,j,result,flag;
    for(j=2;j<i;j++){
        result=i/j;
        if(result==0){
            flag=0;
            return flag;
            break;
        }
        else {
            flag=1;
            
        }
        
        
    }
    if(flag==1){
        return flag;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In the `prime` function, when and where do you initialize the variable `i`? What is `i` supposed to be used for? Perhaps you meant to use `n` instead of `i`?

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info in your C compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) compile as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: Also, `i/j` is the wrong way to calculate primes. You should be using the modulo operator `%` instead.

Comment: Also, enable all compiler warnings and [pay heed to any warnings](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_warnings.html).

Comment: Lastly, please learn how to use a *debugger*, and how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That should have helped you solve your problems quite quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code can help you

I use a boolean function which returns 1 if the number is prime and 0 if the number is not prime

I use loop for from 2 to N and I check each number if he is prime or not by the function

Note: 0 is not prime because it has infinite number of divisors and 1 has only one divisor (itself)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool prime(int n);

int main()
{
    for(int i=2;i<=100;i++)
    {

        if(prime(i))
        {
            printf("[%d]",i);
        }
    }
}

bool prime(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    while(i<=(n/2))
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
             return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @nikos.grigoriadis It's a code dump with no explanation that doesn't help the user with the code they asked about.

Comment: Please don't encourage [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nikos.grigoriadis Sorry a lot ,I explain my code just now